# Automated column renaming when combining data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's assume that I have these data.frames:

```
d1 <- data.frame(a = 1:7,b = 1:7,c = 1:7)
d2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5,b = 1:5,c = 1:5)
d3 <- data.frame(a = 1:6,b = 1:6,c = 1:6)
```

I want to append the d2 and d3 data.frame on the first one by the common value of a column but because the columns in the other two data.frames have the same names I want to rename them like `d2$b.2` and `d3$b.3` and c columns as well.

I tried to do this:

```
for (i in 1:3)
{   
  for (j in 2:length(paste0("d",i)))
  {
    setnames((paste0("d",i),
              paste(colnames(paste0("d",i)[j],
                             paste(paste(colnames(paste0("d",i)[j],i)))
  }

}
```

But something is going wrong.

My ojective is to have a dataframe like this

```
a b c b.1 c.1 b.2 c.2
1 1 1  1   1   1   1 
2 2 2  2   2   2   2
3 3 3  3   3   3   3
4 4 4  4   4   4   4 
5 5 5  5   5   5   5 
6 6 6  NA  NA  6   6 
7 7 7  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: How about `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "a"), mget(paste0("d", 1:3)))`  Or if you need just cbinding then `data.frame(d1, d2[-1], d3[-1])`

Comment: It helps that you posted your input data; the question would be even clearer and more useful to future readers if you showed your desired output.

Comment: Thank you for the imidiate answer. Ok my mistake, the 3 dataframes have different length so data.frame(d1, d2[-1], d3[-1]) cant be used.

Comment: Then, the first one should work fine